# Build Succeeded but Unstable

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3, pom.xml

I am building a Maven project by specifying the POM.xml file and configuring the Subversion path, but ending with this message.. It is saying Build successful but unstable, can some one please advise me on this as i am new with Maven;

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-11-28T12:44:08+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\TCLG\HUB_Console\POM.xml to HUB_Maven/HUB_Console/1.3.1.RELEASE/HUB_Console-1.3.1.RELEASE.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\TCLG\HUB_Console\target\HUB_Console-1.3.1.RELEASE.war to HUB_Maven/HUB_Console/1.3.1.RELEASE/HUB_Console-1.3.1.RELEASE.war
channel stopped
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Comment: Maybe some integration tests will not be successful?

Comment: i tried to build another maven project it build successful, with last message as:
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: with the above project(mentioned at top) only i am getting unstable result, rest i am getting Success message at the last... not getting any idea

Comment: check the link, `UNSTABLE` means some test failed, because Jenkins by default injects the `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to the `MAVEN_OPTS`, hence Maven is ignoring test failing and completing with `BUILD SUCCESS` but then Jenkins is terminating the build as `UNSTABLE`